# Swing layouts combine box and flow

Tags: java, swing, layout

I use a panel with boxlayout and then add panels with flowlayout so I can break a row when I want...but idk how do reduce the space between flowlayout panels in the boxlayout:

```
JPanel search = new JPanel();
BoxLayout bl = new BoxLayout(search, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
search.setLayout(bl);
```

What method should I use to reduce the space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `BoxLayout` will attempt to grow/shrink the panel based on the space available. Override the `getMaximumSize()` method of the panel to return the preferred size of the panel.

```
@Override
public Dimension getMaximumSize()
{
    return getPreferredSize();
}
```

Comment: how can i do that? just create another class called jpanelmod and extend jpanel and put that method in there?